# Concurrent SFTP file transfer using c# and SharpSSH

Tags: c#, sharpssh

I am using [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) for uploading & downloading files via SFTP.

It works with up to 2 connections at a time. Any more than this fails.

Why won't it work with more than 2 connections at a time?

Comment: Show us the relevant code, also this might be a setting on the ssh server have you tried with another sftp client?

Comment: What happens to the 3rd connection? Are you getting an error?